# Most computationally intensive algorithm.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computability

I am trying to develop a benchmark to stress the CPUs on the Server for some HPC (High Performance computing) application. 
   Please help me with some Algorithm that is believed to very CPU intensive.
   I saw algorithms to calculate primes using Newton's method - any better idea than this ?

Comment: Have you considered using some known synthetic benchmark program (e.g. Whetstone/Dhrystone)?

Comment: Can you share a link to your example?

Comment: Also note, that most CPU's are multi-core nowadays, which means that you should either run the same algorithm on multiple threads, or choose one that utilizes the parallelism.

Comment: What, specifically, are you out to test?  Some CPUs perform better than others for what concerns floating point operations.  Others can perform well due to onboard caching, making it ideal for problems which demand a certain amount of memory to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GIMPS](http://mersenne.org/) is very good at stressing CPUs.